# 3d scatter plot with mplot3d with missing frequency as z axis

Tags: matplotlib, histogram, scatter-plot, mplot3d

I am trying to plot some data but I only have my x and y axis given. I would like to get the frequency for my z axis like I would in a histogram. But I don't really want a histogram, rather a scatter plot or a surface plot.

This is my histogram right now, quite messy. 
[image]
Is it possible to use the function of the histogram to get the frequency of the points but have a scatter/surface plot instead? Or to change the bars of the histogram to something like dots or something similar?

None of my data points have the same value, so I would like them to be sorted in intervals, like [0,0.05] or so, that's why I am trying to find another solution than calculating this.

Comment: numpy has a 2-D histogram function. mplot3d can easily plot its output as a surface.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. If you don't have any z values, how can the bars in your barplot have heights? In turn this lets me think that you already have the frequencies available, so you can directly plot them using whatever plot you wish.